# Split a Flac file and create a cue sheet on OS X

Tags: macos, audio, flac, cue-sheet

I'm looking for a way (software or command line tool) to achieve the following on Mac OS X.

- Take a single Flac file with its Cue sheet.
- Split it into several tracks.
- Automaticaly  generate a new cue sheet containing the splitted tracks information based on the single cue sheet.

I use XLD a lot. I've looked into xAct as well and tried with shntool with no success.

Comment: So in this Main Cue sheet it will have the information on how long each Track within the Flac file. And you want to automatically make a new Cue Sheet for each of the Track files. [This](http://www.techisky.com/software/medieval-cue-splitter-mac.html) may help you. It has alternatives to a  Program called Medieval Cue splitter.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [SBooth's Rip](http://sbooth.org/Rip/) to rip the CD's to CUE+FLAC and SBooth's Max to convert the FLAC into individual MP3 files.

You can also try **Medieval CUE Splitter**, but Medieval CUE Splitter is a Windows-based tool and there is still no plan for developing the Mac version. If you insist to run Medieval CUE Splitter on Mac, you need to spend $249 to get VMware Workstation Virtual machine which will allow you run Medieval CUE Splitter on Mac. That is too expensive.

There is [an alternative Mac version of Medieval CUE Splitter](http://www.faasoft.com/articles/medieval-cue-splitter-for-mac.html). Maybe you can also give it a try.